# Django override default admin register form

Tags: python, django, django-admin, modelform

I know how to override `UserCreationForm` but it works only on users, not on admin registration.

Here is my case...

I have modified the **default user model** and it has now the field `user_company` which cannot be Null:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_company = models.ForeignKey("UserCompany", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have overriden the UserCreationForm:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user_company = UserCompany() ## create a new company and assign it to the new user
        user_company.save()

        user = super(UserRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)        
        user.user_company_id = user_company.pk

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

All this works fine for normal users. But when I try to `python manage.py createsuperuser` in the console, after entering the admins username and password, I get an error that

> the field `user_company` cannot be Null

Comment: Have you considered overwriting the save method of your user, so the user_company gets populated everywhere, including the admin?

Comment: @jTiKey thanks for your suggestion. "ibaguio" has written the code below. It helped me. I was thinking in the wrong way, never thought about changing the save method instead of a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating a new UserCompany in the database, just an in memory object, replace

```
user_company = UserCompany() ## create a new company and assign it to the new user
```

with something like

```
user_company = UserCompany.objects.create()
```

I think it is best to move the creation of default UserCompany in the User's save function instead of having it in the form

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   user_company = models.ForeignKey("UserCompany", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if getattr(self, "user_company", None) is None:
            self.user_company = UserCompany.objects.create()

       super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I get this error: ```File "C:\Users\.......\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 194, in __get__
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist("%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name))
app_login.models.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no user_company.```

Comment: I am sorry, but now a similar error: ```NameError: name 'user_company' is not defined``` . But I have solved it another way. In your old code, it should look like ```if self.user_company_id is None:``` so ```user_company``` change to ```user_company_id``` . When I use it that way, it works. Do you think it's OK to work so?

Comment: Should be: 

if not self.user_company:

Comment: One more suggestion: the last line ```super(self, User)``` I had to changes places ```super(User, self)```

Comment: oh god, user_company should be a string ("user_company"). i was quite sleepy when i wrote the code. user_company_id should work fine also. @alispa

Comment: No problem. Thank you very much for you help. I have marked the answer as correct.